# Convert String Value into Datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with my query

```
USE [db]
GO

SELECT 
    TD.ID, LOM.ScanDate, RD.ProcessorType, RD.ProcessorResult, RD.Score  
FROM 
    [dbo].[LogicalObject_Metadatas] LOM WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN 
    [dbo].[LogicalObject] LO WITH(NOLOCK) ON LO.ID = LOM.OBJECTID
JOIN 
    [db2].[dbo].[JobData] JD With(NOLOCK) ON LO.DOCUMENTID = JD.DocumentID
JOIN 
    [db2].[dbo].[TaskData] TD WITH(NOLOCK) ON JD.ID = TD.ParentID
JOIN 
    [db2].[dbo].[RecognitionData] RD WITH(NOLOCK) ON TD.ID = RD.ID
WHERE
    LOM.[Source] = 'MANUFAST_AVR_DNN_QA'
    AND LOM.[ScanDate] > '2018-10-01'
    AND LOM.[ScanDate] < '2018-10-16'
    AND RD.[ProcessorType] IN ('F05AM', 'F06', 'F08', 'F09', 'F11', 'F12A')
```

I want to convert the `[ProcessorResult]` into datetime if the `[ProcessorType]` is `= F05AM`; if not, to be the way it is.

I have tried to use IF, cast but no result.

This is the way query is looking :

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: There are other values in ProcessorResult that match the search criteria that cannot be converted to a datetime - "3" for example. As you cannot have mixed types you would need to reformat the 6 character dates into whatever *string* format you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement in your `select` clause to achieve this, along with some `stuff` calls to handle your input format of `DDMMYY` (replace the `120` style with any other one if you prefer):

```
select 
    TD.ID,
    LOM.ScanDate,
    RD.ProcessorType,
    case 
        when RD.ProcessorType = 'F05AM' and ISDATE(RD.ProcessorResult) = 1
        then convert(varchar,convert(datetime,stuff(stuff(RD.ProcessorResult,5,0,'.'),3,0,'.'), 4),120)  
        else RD.ProcessorResult 
    end as ProcessorResult,
    RD.Score  
from [dbo].[LogicalObject_Metadatas] LOM with (nolock)
join [dbo].[LogicalObject] LO with(nolock) on LO.ID = LOM.OBJECTID
join [db2].[dbo].[JobData] JD with(nolock) on LO.DOCUMENTID = JD.DocumentID
join [db2].[dbo].[TaskData] TD with(nolock) on JD.ID = TD.ParentID
join [db2].[dbo].[RecognitionData] RD with(nolock) on TD.ID = RD.ID
where LOM.[Source] = 'MANUFAST_AVR_DNN_QA'
and LOM.[ScanDate] > '2018-10-01'
and LOM.[ScanDate] < '2018-10-16'
and RD.[ProcessorType] IN ('F05AM','F06','F08','F09','F11','F12A')
```

It's probably not advisable to have a mixture of data types in the same column though, as you won't be able to do much of any use with these dates in the way of aggregation or analysis while there are non-date values mixed in there.

Answer (score 1):

The most important point is that you cannot have a column that is sometimes a date/time and sometimes not.  Columns have fixed types.

You can convert the string into a date with some string manipulation.  This creates a *date* column:

```
select (case when ProcessorType = 'F05AM'
             then convert(date, '20' + right(ProcessorResult, 2) + substring(ProcessorResult, 3, 2) + left(ProcessorResult, 2))
        end)
```

You just want a string that *looks* like a date, so I would do:

```
select (case when ProcessorType = 'F05AM'
             then '20' + right(ProcessorResult, 2) + substring(ProcessorResult, 3, 2) + left(ProcessorResult, 2)
             else ProcessorResult
        end)
```

Comment: Is `case when ProcessorType is = 'F05AM'` valid syntax? I have assumed MSSQL based on what appear to be SSMS in the question, and so would expect `case when ProcessorType = 'F05AM'`...

Comment: @3N1GM4 . . . No it is not.  Thank you.